# Custom Back Office Tab Doesn't Visible in Prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.7

I'm new on developing module of Prestashop and I use version of 1.7.4.2. I'm trying to developing a module and I have to create a custom tab in left menu in back office. I tried this way which is in the Prestashop official documentation(https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/tabs/). But custom tab doesn't visible in the back office. Here I add my code and my file names. Can anyone help me about where is my mistake? Thank you so much.

**My Files**

driveorder

-driveorder.php

-logo.png

-controllers

--admin

---AdminDriveOrder.php

And there is driveorder.php file which is I created custom tab.

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class driveorder extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'driveorder'; /* This is the 'technic' name, this should equal to filename (mycustommodule.php) and the folder name */
        $this->tab = 'administration'; /* administration, front_office_features, etc */
        $this->version = '1.0.0'; /* Your module version */
        $this->author = 'Sertac Bazancir'; /* I guess it was clear */
        $this->need_instance = 0; /* If your module need an instance without installation */
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); /* Your compatibility with prestashop(s) version */
        $this->bootstrap = true; /* Since 1.6 the backoffice implements the twitter bootstrap */

        parent::__construct(); /* I need to explain that? */

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Drive Order'); /* This is the name that merchant see */
        $this->description = $this->l('Google Drive integration for virtual products.'); /* A short description of functionality of this module */

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?'); /* This is a popup message before the uninstall */

        $this->tabs = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Drive Order', // One name for all langs
                'class_name' => 'AdminDriveOrder',
                'visible' => true,
                'parent_class_name' => 'SELL'
            )
        );

    }

    public function install(){
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive()){
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
        }
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._DB_PREFIX_."drive_product`(
        `id_product` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        `id_drive` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL )";
        $result = Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);
        if (!parent::install() OR !$result OR !$this->registerHook('actionPaymentConfirmation')){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall(){
        $sql = "DROP TABLE `"._DB_PREFIX_."drive_product`";
        $result = Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);
        if (!parent::uninstall() OR !$result OR !Configuration::deleteByName('driveorder')){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function hookActionPaymentConfirmation($params){
        global $smarty;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There is defiantly a bug in prestashop, every time I reset the module it behave different - sometime the tab is available sometime not.

Comment: Over a year later and I am facing the same issue.. did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
'parent_class_name' => 'SELL'
```

Try this:

```
'parent_class_name' => 'AdminParentOrders'
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for answer. I tried it but unfortunately it still doesn't visible.

Comment: Have you reset the module?

Comment: Yes. I have reset it after changes.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to name your controller file `AdminDriveOrderController.php` instead of `AdminDriveOrder.php`